# Find and extract words/names from a string beginning with specific character

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I've got some rows in Google Sheets that contain strings. I want to extract certain parts from this string and enter them into another cell:
specifically, **I want to extract words/names that begin with the character "@"**.

For example in the string "Hello @Henry how are you" I want the next cell along to display only "@Henry", removing all the other words.

There are also cases when there are multiple names beginning with @ and I would want all of these returned (preferably in separate columns).

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit:** dummy spreadsheet below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TupcKRHHi94Q3OLmZS0-eEWNwbEZF90gjymoyem3GFI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Share the spreadsheet to make it easier to understand what's happening

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TupcKRHHi94Q3OLmZS0-eEWNwbEZF90gjymoyem3GFI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please allow access as well as edit your spreadsheet. At the moment it is totally blocked. I can not access. You can do this in the upper right corner, in a green bar.

Comment: Ahh sorry. Here you go. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TupcKRHHi94Q3OLmZS0-eEWNwbEZF90gjymoyem3GFI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LEFT` function is for you to find values from the left-to-right summation and the `RIGHT` function does just the opposite. The `FIND` function is to find at what position exactly text you want. It automatically starts counting characters for `LEFT` or `RIGHT`. And the `LEN` function is to count the total value of characters that exist in a cell, so you need to use it in the `RIGHT` function, because you need to count the total character value minus the position you are looking to separate.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this **single robust formula in cell `B2`**:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if(LEN(A2:A),TRIM(SPLIT(
                 REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(join("♣︎", A2:A))),"♣︎")),"(?:.?(@[A-Z][a-z]\b))|(.*)","$1"&" ")," ")
                        ),"")),"")
```

**An even simpler formula** can be used if you don't have any empty rows in between your answers:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(
         REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(join("♣︎", A2:A))),"♣︎")),"(?:.?(@[A-Z][a-z]\b))|(.*)","$1"&" ")," ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` + a `filter` you can extract the words with the pattern you need : `@ + upper case + whatever`

```
=transpose(
      filter(
             transpose(SPLIT(A2," ")),
             REGEXMATCH(transpose(SPLIT(A2," ")),"@[A-Z]")
             )
)
```